# Jersey Client: too many Conent-Type header values

Tags: java, json, rest, header, jersey

in my web application I invoke a service like this:

```
Response response = null;
Builder builder = webTarget.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

if (this.headers != null) { 
    builder.headers(this.headers); // headers is empty in this case
}

response = builder.method(methodName.toString(), Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType()), Response.class);

if (typeOfT.equals(Response.class)) {
    return (T) response;

} else {
    handleException(response);
    return gson.fromJson(response.readEntity(String.class), typeOfT);
}
```

The service responds correctly but when I try to deserialize the response, this exception is thrown:

> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeaderValueException: Too many
>   "Content-Type" header values: "[application/json; charset=utf-8,
>   application/json]"

I use:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
   <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will get this error when the response has more than one `Content-Type` response header. What you can do id reset the header to just use one by using `response.getHeaders().putSingle()`. This will override the double headers and just leave you with one.

```
response.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
return gson.fromJson(response.readEntity(String.class), typeOfT);
```